# Is the set of all two-element subsets of Z+ countable or uncountable?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I said it is countable.

Let **Y**={**(x,y**)| **x,y** belong to the set **Z+**}.

**Z+** denotes the set of positive integers.

Then **Y=Z+** x **Z+**. Here **Z+** x **Z+** is the cartesian product of the set of positive integers.
There is a corollary that states the set **Z+** x  **Z+** is countably infinite. By definition, a set is said to be countable if it is either finite or countably infinite.

In this case, **Z+** x **Z+** is countable. Then **Y** is countable. Therefore, the  set of all two-element subsets of **Z+** is countable.

Is this correct answer, and the right way to prove this?

Comment: The answer that 2-subsets of $\mathbb Z^+$ form a countable family is correct.  However I think it would be prudent to detail how that family relates to what you have called $\mathbf Y$.

Comment: You really do need to go into a bit more detail to explain why countability of $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$ implies countability of $\Bbb Y$.

Comment: Lol your proof is "let's prove theorem X. Now there is a corollary that theorem X is true. Therefore theorem X is true."

Comment: Hint: The set of rational numbers is basically $\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z$. How do you prove rational numbers are countable?

Comment: Also if you want to be technical, your definition for $\mathbb{Y}$ is not the correct one, because it will also contain all singletons of $\mathbb{Z}+$. Why?